# Test presence of elements in each row and column of a 2D array - java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I written a short program that randomly populates a 10x10 2D array with 0s and 1s. I want check the array to see if each row and column contains more than five 1s.

I've done it using 2 separate nested for-loops but is there a way of checking each row and column using only 1 nested for-loop and printing out the result for each row/column? I can't work out a way of combining what I have into one nested loop. Many thanks for any suggestions :)

Here's my code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] array = new int[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = (int) (2 * Math.random());
        }
    }
    System.out.print("---THE MATRIX---\n");
    System.out.println();
    for (int[] arr : array) {
        for (int value : arr) {
            System.out.print(value + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    fiveOnes(array);
}


private static void fiveOnes(int[][] array) {
    System.out.println("---MORE THAN FIVE ONES THROUGHOUT THE MATRIX---\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int oneCount = 0;
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] == 1) {
                oneCount++;
            }
        }
        if (oneCount > 5)
            flag = true;
        System.out.println("Row " + (i + 1) + ": " + flag);
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
        int oneCount = 0;
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j][i] == 1) {
                oneCount++;
            }
        }
        if (oneCount > 5) {
            flag = true;
        }
        System.out.println("Column " + (i + 1) + ": " + flag);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int oneCountRow = 0;
    int oneCountColumn = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (array[i][j] == 1) {
            oneCountRow++;
        }
        if (array[j][i] == 1) {
            oneCountColumn++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Row " + (i + 1) + ": " + (oneCountRow > 5));
    System.out.println("Column " + (i + 1) + ": " + (oneCountColumn> 5));
}
```

or for free size:

```
    int maxLenght = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        maxLenght = Math.max(maxLenght, array[i].length);
    }
    maxLenght = Math.max(maxLenght, array.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLenght; i++) {
        int oneCountRow = 0;
        int oneCountColumn = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < maxLenght; j++) {
            if (j < array[i].length && i < array.length && array[i][j] == 1) {
                oneCountRow++;
            }
            if (i < array[j].length && j < array.length && array[j][i] == 1) {
                oneCountColumn++;
        }

        System.out.println("Row " + (i + 1) + ": " + (oneCountRow > 5));
        System.out.println("Column " + (i + 1) + ": " + (oneCountColumn> 5));
}
```

Comment: Instead of hard coding `i < 10` and `j < 10` it might be safer to use the actual length of the array instead.

Comment: Great this works nicely. Agree with @BasdeGroot but this is basically what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: actual length may be different for different lines

Comment: An improvement would be to stop as soon as either `oneCountRow` or `oneCountColumn` reach `5`.

Comment: The improvement will be to stop as soon as BOTH the OneCountRow and oneCountColumn have reached 5. if (oneCountRow > 5 && oneCountColumn> 5) break;

Answer (score 0):

You could try to collect the booleans in two flat arrays. One for columns and one for rows. Then you need only one nested loop and use the appropriate index for those two flat arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts on the solution:

You could create an "count array" of size `max(n, m) * 2` where `n` and `m` are dimensions of the matrix and initialize it with `0`s. The `2` represents whether it's count for a column or a row (e.g. index `0` represents columns and `1` rows). Then you increment the representative value in that array when you find a `1` (for both cols and rows). Finding the right index is just matter of some modular arithmetics.